# symfony twig custom submit label form

Tags: symfony, twig, symfony-3.4, twig-extension, symfony3.x

I want to customize my form submit button label from "submit" to "Edit" in some of pages , and "submit" to "Add" in some other pages, with twig and Symfony 3.4 as this :

```
{{ form(form) }}
{{ form_widget(form.submit,{'label':'edit'}) }}
```

but this is not working for me :/ I see the documentation about all of that in the Symfony offcial website, but this didn't help me .

So can any one help me please?

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of form_widget, try [form_row](https://symfony.com/doc/3.2/reference/forms/twig_reference.html)

```
{{ form_row(form.submit, { 'label': 'edit' }) }}
```

Comment: Thank you it works good , just I have a last quetion : how can I add this form_row as a single customized row and display others in a signle line (without writing all rows) thank you in advance

Comment: like this : <div class="form-group">{{ form_row(form.Name) }}</div>
is that what you want ?

Comment: or you want to add custom parameters like class or any other data paramters to that form element ?

Comment: Not this, 
I mean , I want for example to write :

{{ form(all 1st_parts_of_all_forms_elements) }} then finally
{{ form_row(form.submit, { 'label': 'edit' }) }}

to prevent writing all form rows ..
I mean to prevent writing like this :
{{ form_row(form.Name) }}
{{ form_row(form.LastName) }}
{{ form_row(form.Age) }}
..
{{ form_row(form.submit, { 'label': 'edit' }) }}

did you understand what I mean please ?

Comment: Ohh ok, now I got it so for that you can simply use for loop [https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/for.html] on form object.

Comment: I'm sorry but the page that you sent to me ,  is Not Found :(

Comment: Ohh Sorry, please check now : http://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/for.html

Comment: Thank you , but I didn't find the right answer for my last question.

Answer (score 0):

in form widget it is also is posible, you can also set class for bootstrap btn class for example

in FormType add

```
$builder
  ->add('save', SubmitType::class)
```

in TWIG

```
{{ form_widget(form.save, {'attr': {'class': 'btn btn-warning'},  'label': 'YourLabelName'  } ) }}
```